# Doubt on definition of Doob's notion of upcrossing

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, definition, martingales

From **Jacod-Protter**:

> **DEFINITION** Let $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ be a submartingale and $a<b$. The number of *upcrossings* of an interval $[a,b]$ is the number of times a process crosses from below $a$ and to above $b$ *at a later time*. Using stopping times, this translates into defining:
>   \begin{equation}
> T_0=0
> \end{equation}
>   and inductively for $j\geq0$:
>   \begin{equation}
> S_{j+1}=\min\{k>T_j:X_k\leq a\}
> \end{equation}
>   \begin{equation}
> T_{j+1}=\min\{k>S_{j+1}:X_k\geq b\}
> \end{equation}
>   with convention that $\min\{\emptyset\}=+\infty$ and $\max\{\emptyset\}=0$. Finally:
>   \begin{equation}
> U_{n}=\max\{j:T_j\leq n\}
> \end{equation}
>   with $U_n$ representing the number of upcrossings of $[a,b]$ before time $n$.

I have tried to verify this definition by means of a simple example and I get unexpected results. The example unfolds as follows:

**MY EXAMPLE**

- Fix $a= 0,5$, $b=1,2$;
- $X_0=0,2$, $X_1=0,7$, $X_2=1,4$, $X_3=0,65$; $X_4=0,1$, $X_5=1,5$;

which means that there are just two upcrossings of the interval $[a,b]$ before time $n=5$, just one upcrossing before time $n=4$ and time $n=3$ and time $n=2$, and no upcrossing before time $n=1$ and $n=0$ **(See the figure attached below so as to have a clear visualization of the example)**.

Hence, by definition of $T_{j+1}$ and $S_{j+1}$, one has that:

- $T_0=0$;
- $S_1=4$, $T_1=5$;
- $S_j=T_j=+\infty$ for $j\geq 2$.

This means that, by definition of $U_n$:

- $U_0=0$ (**AS EXPECTED**);
- $U_1=0$ (**AS EXPECTED**);
- $U_2=0$ (**UNEXPECTED, I WOULD EXPECT $U_2=1$**);
- $U_3=0$ (**UNEXPECTED, I WOULD EXPECT $U_3=1$**);
- $U_4=0$ (**UNEXPECTED, I WOULD EXPECT $U_4=1$**);
- $U_5=1$ (**UNEXPECTED, I WOULD EXPECT $U_5=2$**);

At this point, if instead one considers the definition of $S_{j+1}$ as follows:
\begin{equation}
S_{j+1}=\min\{k\geq T_j:X_k\leq a\}
\end{equation}
(that is **with *$k\geq T_j$* in place of *$k > T_j$***), by definition of $T_{j+1}$ and *by the new definition of $S_{j+1}$*, one would have:

- $T_0=0$;
- $S_1=0$, $T_1=2$;
- $S_2=4$, $T_2=5$;
- $S_j=T_j=+\infty$ for $j\geq 3$;

and so

- $U_0=0$ (**AS EXPECTED**);
- $U_1=0$ (**AS EXPECTED**);
- $U_2=1$ (**AS EXPECTED**);
- $U_3=1$ (**AS EXPECTED**);
- $U_4=1$ (**AS EXPECTED**);
- $U_5=2$ (**AS EXPECTED**).

In conclusion, it seems to me that $U_n=\max\{j:T_j\leq n\}$ is the correct definition of the number of upcrossings of $[a,b]$ before time $n$  **ONLY IF** $S_{j+1}=\min\{k\geq T_j:X_k\leq a\}$ and **NOT IF** $S_{j+1}=\min\{k > T_j:X_k\leq a\}$.

*Is my observation correct?*

> *VISUALIZATION OF THE ABOVE EXAMPLE*

[image]

Comment: I would change your indexing of $X$ to start at 1 but your observation is correct.

Comment: Note that off-by-one errors aren't really a big deal here.  I assume this is part of a proof of the martingale convergence theorem, in which case we only care about when the number of upcrossings is finite.

Comment: Yeah, actually this is a result just before the martingale convergence theorem itself on Jacod-Protter. I got your point, that's comforting. Anyway, you confirm that there is this little (not significant, as you have just shown) error, don't you? @NateEldredge

Comment: Yes, I agree; an upcrossing that starts at time 1 is not counted.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time and help @NateEldredge

Comment: Thank you a lot @KingJ, I agree